# How to add an element to a tuple in a list in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have the following types and database:-

```
type Title = String
type Singer = [String]
type Year = Int
type Fan = String
type Fans = [Fan]

type Song = (Title, Signer, Year, Fans)

type Database = [Song]  

songDatabase :: Database
songDatabase = [("Wrapped up", ["Olly Murs"], 2014, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
    ("Someone Like you", ["Adele"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]), 
("Drunk in Love", ["Beyonce", "Jay Z"], 2014, ["tom", "Lucy"])]
```

I want to add a fan to the last tuple in the list. Do i do this through using addToAl or is there other methods i can use?

Do i have to search for the data and delete it and then add the data I want? or is there a way to just add for example, "John" to the fans in the someone like you tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add a tuple to an existing list, all values in Haskell are immutable.  Instead, you can construct a new list that contains the values you want.  The best way to accomplish this is to first write a function that can add a fan to a single film:

```
addFan :: Fan -> Song -> Song
addFan fan (title, singer, year, fans) = ???
```

Then you can write a function updates a particular song in the database:

```
addFanInDB :: Fan -> Title -> Database -> Database
addFanInDB fan songTitle [] = []
addFanInDB fan songTitle (song:db) = ???
```

Since this looks very much like homework, I'm not going to give you a full solution since that defeats the purpose of the assignment.  You'll need to fill in the `???` yourself.

Comment: I don't wish to add a whole tuple to the list, I just want to add a single value for example, "John" to the fans in the someone like you tuple. Can you not do this? if not I will try the above approach and try and work it out

Comment: @TomPhillippe you can not modify any value in haskell, by design they are immutable. You are required to construct a new value instead of modifying an existing one.

Comment: when using the recursion in the addFanInDB do you call the addFan function?

Comment: @TomPhillippe Correct.  Basically, what you want to do is iterate over the list using pattern matching and recursion.  When you find the song that matches `songTitle`, use `addFan fan song` to create a new one to take it's place.  Alternatively, you could write another function that does `\song -> if songTitle == titleOfSong song then addFan fan song else song` that only creates a new one if the title matches, then you can use `map` with that new function.

Comment: I am very new to haskell, in the example you have given above, i have managed to get addFan working, then i understand that for the second ?? i need to have a recursive call that checks the database for the `songTitle` and then you use `addFan fan song` to add it, however i see that the user is inputing a database where do i use this?

Comment: still stuck on the last part of this, any more help would be of huge assistance please @bheklilr

Comment: @TomPhillippe `addFanInDB fan songTitle (song:db) = (if titleMatches songTitle song then addFan fan song : db else ???`  The way I've written it here is to stop iterating over the DB once the song is found, using the `titleMatches` function that I hope is clear enough to fill in a definition for.  I'm still leaving you the recursion to fill in.